# How can I get Xcode to show documentation comments again after uninstalling dash

Tags: xcode, dashcode

I installed 'dash' https://kapeli.com/dash , it was supposed to be better than the apple documantation but i didnt like it, now i really want to go back to the old apple documantation where i just press alt/option left mouse click and it pops up a description and info.
Now everytime i press alt/option click it pops me an alert of searching for Dash[image]

What can i do to get apple doc again??

Answer (score 0):

After updating my xcode it revealed the apple documentation.